# SNMP - need help with terminology

Tags: terminology, snmp

In many resources, I see that community strings are also called default passwords. But in the Server Manager, I see "Community name" and it makes more sense. 
So why people often use the phrase "default password"? If we enumerate the information by their name...

Answer (score 1):

"Community Name" are used in SNMP v1 and v2 as an authentication asset: one presenting the good "Community Name" in his request will be authorized to get/set informations.

That's probably why people call this "default password" ...